# Enable Function Key Lock when using external keyboard/Disable when using internal keyboard on Mac Book Pro

Tags: macos, keyboard, bluetooth

When I'm developing I almost always have an external Bluetooth keyboard connected to my Mac Book Pro, and prefer the function lock to be active so the F1-F12 keys work without having to press the fn key. But when using the internal keyboard, I tend to be doing more casual things and brightness/volume etc are more commonly used.

Can I enable/disable the function lock depending on which keyboard I am using?

Comment: What's the brand of the external keyboard?

Comment: It one of the new [Apple Magic Keyboard](http://www.apple.com/uk/shop/product/MLA22B/A/magic-keyboard-british-english?fnode=56)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this work you have to use a third party tool: Karabiner.

To enable this you have to create a filter for the external keyboard and invert all function/consumer keys.

Prerequisites:

1. Download, install and open [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/)
2. Open in the menulet Karabiner -> Preferences
3. Open the tab *Misc & Uninstall*
4. Hit the button <kbd>Launch EventViewer</kbd>
5. Hit the tab *Devices*
6. Make a note of the vendor and product ID of the external keyboard
7. Close the EventViewer
8. Hit the button <kbd>Open private.xml</kbd>
9. Open the file private.xml with an appropriate editor
10. Enter the customized keycode and replace the vendor and product ID by IDs found above

    ```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <root>
      <devicevendordef>
        <vendorname>Apple</vendorname>
        <vendorid>0x05ac</vendorid>
      </devicevendordef>
      <deviceproductdef>
        <productname>ExternalKeyboard</productname>
        <productid>0x0256</productid>
      </deviceproductdef>
      <item>
        <name>Function to Consumer for External Keyboard</name>
        <identifier>private.function2consumerExtK</identifier>
        <device_only>DeviceVendor::Apple, DeviceProduct::ExternalKeyboard</device_only>
        <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F1, ConsumerKeyCode::BRIGHTNESS_DOWN</autogen>
        <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F2, ConsumerKeyCode::BRIGHTNESS_UP</autogen>
        ...
      </item>
      <item>
        <name>Consumer to Function for External Keyboard</name>
        <identifier>private.consumer2functionExtK</identifier>
        <device_only>DeviceVendor::Apple, DeviceProduct::ExternalKeyboard</device_only>
        <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::BRIGHTNESS_DOWN, ModifierFlag::FN, KeyCode::F1</autogen>
        <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::BRIGHTNESS_UP, ModifierFlag::FN, KeyCode::F2</autogen>
        ...
      </item>
    </root>
    ```

    Replace the ellipses by all other necessary consumer and function keys
11. Save the file
12. Open in the menulet Karabiner -> Preferences the tab *Change Key*
13. Hit the ReloadXML button
14. Enable the remappings. They should be listed at the beginning.

The final behavior should be as following with the function lock activated:

Internal keyboard:

<kbd>F1</kbd>: F1
<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>: brightness up

External keyboard:

<kbd>F1</kbd>: brightness up
<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>: F1

etc.

If you disable or skip the *Consumer to Function for External Keyboard* part it should act like this:

<kbd>F1</kbd>: brightness up
<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>: brightness up

which means that the "function key layer" is disabled and only the consumer key layer is working.

etc.

---

Other possible keycodes:

```
KeyCode::EXPOSE_ALL,                 KeyCode::F3</autogen>
KeyCode::DASHBOARD,                  KeyCode::F4</autogen>
KeyCode::LAUNCHPAD,                  KeyCode::F4</autogen>
ConsumerKeyCode::KEYBOARDLIGHT_LOW,  KeyCode::F5</autogen>
ConsumerKeyCode::KEYBOARDLIGHT_HIGH, KeyCode::F6</autogen>
ConsumerKeyCode::MUSIC_PREV,         KeyCode::F7</autogen>
ConsumerKeyCode::MUSIC_PLAY,         KeyCode::F8</autogen>
ConsumerKeyCode::MUSIC_NEXT,         KeyCode::F9</autogen>
ConsumerKeyCode::VOLUME_MUTE,        KeyCode::F10</autogen>
ConsumerKeyCode::VOLUME_DOWN,        KeyCode::F11</autogen>
ConsumerKeyCode::VOLUME_UP,          KeyCode::F12</autogen>
```

Comment: Really sorry for the slow acceptance, thanks for the great answer.